# Symfony2 form validation with html5 and CANCEL button

Tags: html, validation, symfony, twig

I have a contact form on Symfony2 where I put some validators as email, minLength etc.
All those fields are also set as notBlank.

Due to this, HTML5 is also validating those fields (for the email and not blank), which is fine for me.

I have a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**The problem is** that I have another submit button which is a Cancel button:

```
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

With this button, in my controller I am doing a redirect:

```
if( $request->get('cancel') == 'Cancel' )
    return  $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SciForumVersion2Bundle_homepage'));
```

Now, due to the HTML5 validation, I can't redirect because the fields are empty for example.

To reslove that, I have found two solutions, but I don't like them:

1. Disable the HTML 5 validation:

   ```
   <form novalidate>
   ```
2. Use JavaScript

But as I said, I don't like those methods and I am sure that there are some nice Symfony methods to resolve that.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: if you cancel, you don't want to submit, no ? why don't you use a href link and quit the page ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, so instead of using a simble submit button, is there a possibility to use a button with href?

Comment: The better option is using a simple link. It also emphasizes what to do if you want to continue (big button) or cancel (small link).

Comment: Having a button on one side and a cancel link on the other, I prefer two buttons, and play with the colors maybe.

Comment: look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons, it will display links as a button if you add the right class. Useful

Comment: Thank you @JulienRollin. Could you please post an answer (Similar to your first comment about the href). So I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i resume my comment :)

when dealing with form (HTML5 or not) and you want to quit, you don't need to submit and validate any data
You just have to put a simple href link to change the page. Use your favorite css style to have the same look

Tip: you could listen to javascript event **"onbeforeunload"** when user has changed an input value. It alerts the user that he will quit the page

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 19):

Disable the form validation exclusively for the cancel button using `formnovalidate`:

```
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" formnovalidate/>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it does exactly what is desired: it disables form-validation for all fields when set on the "cancel" `submit` button. This works much better for many designers because you can use two `submit` buttons instead of one `submit` button and a link. It is a better semantic description of the page, too.

Answer (score 6):

I see this is an older thread, but I wanted to offer an alternate solution in case others find it useful. I was unsatisfied with other answers on this topic, because I wanted to do three things:

- Not have to do any custom form rendering in each view template (I like to just use `{{ form(form) }}`)
- Have the cancel button appear right next to the submit button (surprisingly tricky, since symfony by default wraps all form buttons in a div tag if you don't do custom rendering)
- Be able to set the cancel action as an option *in the controller*, since the link will vary depending on whether I'm adding or editing, etc

And I wanted to do all this while applying the DRY principle. To start, I extended the base form type to allow a custom option, 'cancel_action':

```
<?php
namespace AcmeBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefined('cancel_action');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('cancel_action', 'string');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        if (isset($options['cancel_action'])) {
            $view->vars['cancel_action'] = $options['cancel_action'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

And registered that form type extension in my config (using alias 'form' so that it would be available for all my forms):

```
acme.form_type_extension:
    class: AcmeBundle\Form\Extension\FormTypeExtension
    tags:
        - {name: form.type_extension, alias: form}
```

Then I used form theming to extend the base form view (I extended the submit_widget block so that the cancel button would be next to the submit button inside the div tag):

```
{# AcmeBundle:Form:fields.html.twig #}

{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block submit_widget -%}
    {%- set type = type|default('submit') -%}
    {{ block('button_widget') }}
    {% if form.parent.vars.cancel_action is defined %}
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ form.parent.vars.cancel_action }}" role="button">Cancel</a>
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock submit_widget -%}
```

And registered that form theme in my twig config so that it would apply by default to all form views:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'AcmeBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Et voila! Now for each form, if I want a cancel button, all I need to do is specify the cancel action as an option when I initialize the form in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AlbumType(), $album, array(
    'cancel_action' => $this->generateUrl('album_home')
));
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Only change I made was to add `style="margin-left: 10px;` and `btn-primary` to the link class due to using Braincrafted's bootstrap.

Comment: @sarahg, this is awesome, thank you, but I had some trouble applying this to symfony 4.1, when using the bootstrap 4 theme, I've had to remove the {% extends from the template fil, don't really now why, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

```
->add('cancel', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Cancel',
            'attr' => array(                       
                    'formnovalidate'=>'formnovalidate'
            ) 
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can Easly Disable Form validation using HTML5 required attribute by **formnovalidate**

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with :

```
<button name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" formnovalidate>Cancel</button>
```