# How not to validate HTML5 text box with required attribute

Tags: html, button, required

I have one HTML text box (for quantity) and two HTML buttons (Add, Cancel) inside my form.

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" required />
    <button type="button">Add</button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I do not want my second button (cancel) to validate the form when clicked.

Is this possible? In ASP.NET, I can use CausesValidation="false" to not trigger the validation.

Comment: Reading material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761202/whats-the-difference-between-novalidate-and-formnovalidate-attributes-of-html5

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this;

```
<button type="button" formnovalidate>Cancel</button>
```

I changed your code:
What you want is that your form should not be validated on click of cancel, so that's why i added the formnovalidate to the button cancel.

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" required />
    <input type="submit">Add</input>
    <input type="submit" formnovalidate>Cancel</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Which one is appropriate to use? formvalidate or novalidate?

Comment: Mix of your 2 answers... formnovalidate :)

Comment: Not working for ASP.NET ImageButton even though I add CausesValidation="false" and formnovalidate for IE11

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `formnovalidate` attribute to your cancel button

```
<button type="button" formnovalidate>Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the formnovalidate-option on the cancel-button, like this:

```
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" formnovalidate/>
```

See [Symfony2 form validation with html5 and CANCEL button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756362/symfony2-form-validation-with-html5-and-cancel-button)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the input button as `runat=server` then you must have the property `causesvalidation="false"` or else if you are simply using html input type button for cancel use `javascript` to redirect to your page on click of cancel.

For eg.
1)

```
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" class="button blue" value="Cancel" **causesvalidation="false"** onserverclick="btnCancel_Click" runat="server" />
```

2)

```
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" class="button blue" value="Cancel" **onclick="GoTo();"**/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GoTo() {
            window.location.href = '../default.aspx';
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code at asp.net 5[enter link description here](http://alduar.blogspot.com) button control

```
<form>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" required />
<button type="button">Add</button>
<button type="button" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">Cancel</button>
```

Aldo Flores Reyes
@alduar
[.net news](http://alduar.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

try this one.it works fine.It will work on submit button

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="inputusername" required />
```