# how to bypass required field validation when clicking the cancel button?

Tags: html, vb.net, cancel-button, required-field

I've used HTML input type for my textboxes to utilize the required attribute. now my dilemma is i cannot go out of the page without filling-up the fields with required attributes. Ive tried using causeValidation set to false but its not working. i can not change my textboxes to asp textboxes because it's going to be a large changes in the page. is there any other way to this?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonCancel" CssClass="cu-btn-direction" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 60px;" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
```

EDIT:

I tried adding validation group but didn't work... what works is setting the UseSubmitBehavior to false http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but as explained in the link it will not work without js enabled. any other way?

Comment: Found this link useful to me... <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202784/how-not-to-validate-html5-text-box-with-required-attribute> it works with or without js...

Answer (score 24):

use **formnovalidate**

```
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" formnovalidate>
```

this bypass all form validation like **required**

Comment: Or just change the type of input `<input type="button" value="Cancel">`