# Access HTML "required" method from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

so I've `asp:textbox` with a `required` method, the problem is when I try to use another `button` like search, the page is asking me to fill the fields with the `required` attribute. Is there any way to remove this on a click from by button with code behind using `vb.net`? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sharad, I solve this problem in another way, not from code behind, I used the `formnovalidate` to bypass the validation on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Set the search button's [CausesValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) property to false.

Comment: Already done but still the same, the page ask me to fill the `textbox`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem you can just put the attribute `formnovalidate` inside the button attibutes and it's done the answer came from this post:

[How not to validate HTML5 text box with required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202784/how-not-to-validate-html5-text-box-with-required-attribute)